# SMTP server on Heroku

Tags: python, email, heroku, dns, smtp

I am trying to build a very simple SMTP server in Python to receive emails from custom domains (e.g., `hi@<my_domain.com>`) and deploy it on Heroku without relying on Postmark or SendGrid.

So far, I…

1. set up a MX record: `@ MX <my_app>.herokuapp.com 10`
2. declared a process: `web: python server.py`
3. instantiated a server: `SMTPServer((<my_host>, <my_port>), None)`

I am not clear on what to use for `<my_host>` and `<my_port>` as well as how the communication works between the MX record and the web process (if that is even the right thing).

Could you provide some guidance and help me better understand that flow?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you want to receive email you would need a POP server and an SMTP to send, right?

Comment: @KristopherIves Unfortunately, I don't have a good example to share. I am asking more about how I should go about it and if it is even doable.

Comment: @EnriqueBruzual Isn't that what `smtpd.SMTPServer` is?

Comment: @gduverger, you probably can't do this. Heroku expects you to bind to one public port (given by the `$PORT` environment variable) and to run a _web_ server on it.

Comment: @Chris Uh, that's what I was afraid of.